# How to select options provided in a textbox using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Link: http://www.bbc.com/weather/

Scenario: Type "reading" on the find a forecast text box. This shows 2 options. How do I select one option using Selenium WebDriver?

I am using the following command to type "reading"

```
driver.findElement(By.id("locator-form-search")).sendKeys("Reading");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following locator to click on the first element (first suggestion displayed after typing):

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='locator-suggestions locator-suggestions-default'] li:nth-child(1)")).click();
```

Similarly you can click on the other element by changing the locator. For example to select the second element:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='locator-suggestions locator-suggestions-default'] li:nth-child(2)")).click();
```

Just to add here, you may need to wait for the elements/suggestions (which you're trying to select) to be visible, before trying to click on those. Use/search for a appropriate wait method for your testing. 
So,

- first you need to type "reading" in the field as you are doing by using `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#locator-form-search")).sendKeys("Reading");`
- then wait for element to be visible
- Then try the above mentioned code to select the desired element.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I added explict wait as you suggested and this worked with a small change in the css path. This is what I did:

```
WebElement suggestedList = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
            .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By
                    .cssSelector("div[class='locator-suggestions locator-suggestions-default'] >ul >li:nth-of-type(1)")));
    driver.findElement(
            By.cssSelector("div[class='locator-suggestions locator-suggestions-default'] >ul >li:nth-of-type(1)"))
            .click();
```